# WPF - Horizontal datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing a WPF project and I'm trying to create a window like this:

[image]

The goal is to have a predone table with rows of products, and when a product is selected this window pops up with  the "Codigo" and "Designação" of the selected product and on the last row should be a text input with default value = 1.
In the picture the orange textbox should be the header of the datagrid that has 2 columns and 3 lines ("Cancelar" and "Registar" are buttons outside the datagrid).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve a grid with 2 columns and 3 rows you can use the Grid control.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid
```

Now you can use the attached properties of Grid to assign certain objects to certain positions inside the grid e.g.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Button at Column 1 and Row 1</Button>
    </Grid
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Can I merge just top two cells to write the header? If so do you know how?

Comment: @TiagoSilva If you use the attached property `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` it will span over 2 columns e.g.
`<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Span Example</Button>`